# Xcode debugger not printing objects

Tags: debugging, xcode4, gdb

Within the past couple of days when I try to print the value of an object in Xcode 4.2 nothing happens,

say for instance I type 'po response' it just returns a blank line. This happens no matter what I type even if there is no object such as 'po asoneuhrc,.u09'. But the value is definitely not null since if I NSLog(@"response: %@", response); in the same location I get back an expected value.

(gdb) po response
(gdb)

Has any one else encountered this before? I have tried restarting both Xcode and my computer but it doesn't always help (it randomly fixes itself).

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No, sometimes it will print them other times it won't I have no idea how to fix it when it does occur though.

Comment: Some bug in Xcode it seems :)